# Extend product custom options select when checked

Tags: product, php, custom-options, custom

I want to extend the default code of the file `/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php`

So that the `<li>` of the custom options got a specific class when selected.
So when a option (radio button) is checked, it should add `class="checked"` to the opper `<li>`.

Already tried this, but that did not added the class when checked:

```
$spanClass = "input-radio";
if ($checked) {
    $spanClass = "input-radio checked";
}

'<span class="' . $spanClass . '">'
```

How can I achieve this?

CODE:

```
        $htmlValue = $_value->getOptionTypeId();
        if ($arraySign) {
            $checked = (is_array($configValue) && in_array($htmlValue, $configValue)) ? 'checked' : '';
        } else {
            $checked = $configValue == $htmlValue ? 'checked' : '';
        }
        $spanClass = "input-radio";
        if ($checked) {
            $spanClass = "input-radio checked";
        }

        $selectHtml .= '<li>' . '<span class="input-radio"><input type="' . $type . '" class="' . $class . ' ' . $require
            . ' product-custom-option"'
            . ($this->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"')
            . ($this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false) ? '0' : ' checked="checked"')
            . ' name="options[' . $_option->getId() . ']' . $arraySign . '" id="options_' . $_option->getId()
            . '_' . $count . '" value="' . $htmlValue . '" ' . $checked . ' price="'
            . $this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false) . '" /></span>'
            . '<span class="label product-option' . $spanClass . '"><label for="options_' . $_option->getId() . '_' . $count . '"><span class="option-name">'
            . $this->escapeHtml($_value->getTitle()) . '</span>' . $priceStr . '</label></span>';
        if ($_option->getIsRequire()) {
            $selectHtml .= '<script type="text/javascript">' . '$(\'options_' . $_option->getId() . '_'
            . $count . '\').advaiceContainer = \'options-' . $_option->getId() . '-container\';'
            . '$(\'options_' . $_option->getId() . '_' . $count
            . '\').callbackFunction = \'validateOptionsCallback\';' . '</script>';
        }
        $selectHtml .= '</li>';
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question.

Comment: @Myron I extend the question, to explain it more